# Worklog gadget for JIRA

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

Is there an ability to create JIRA gadget that shows my total month worklog for 2 projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can create your own plugin with required gadgets using this book: "JIRA 5.x Development Cookbook" by Jobin Kuruvilla. It was useful for me

Answer (score 0):

You can do this [Tempo](http://www.tempoplugin.com/). First create a saved search for your two projects. Then view them in the [Advanced Timesheet](http://wiki.tempoplugin.com/display/TEMPO/Advanced+Timesheet).